# Why mongo aggregate not return a consistent order?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Here my query:

```
db.getCollection('alerts').aggregate([{
  $match: {
    houseId: ObjectId("609100a56ed9f8001351aee3")
  }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: '$type',
        alerts: {
            $push: {
                _id: '$_id',
                type: '$type'
            }
        }
     }
  },
  {
    $project: {
       _id: false,
       type: '$_id.type',
       alerts: '$alerts'
    }

  }
])
```

And result:

```
[{
    "type" : "cool",
    "alerts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("61387e740dc3d853f1eee5b0"),
            "type" : "cool"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "type" : "hot",
    "alerts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("61387e740dc3d853f1eee5b0"),
            "type" : "hot"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("61387e740dc3d853f1eee5b0"),
            "type" : "hot"
        }
    ]
}]
```

but sometime it also return:

```
[{
    "type" : "hot",
    "alerts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("61387e740dc3d853f1eee5b0"),
            "type" : "hot"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("61387e740dc3d853f1eee5b0"),
            "type" : "hot"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "type" : "cool",
    "alerts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("61387e740dc3d853f1eee5b0"),
            "type" : "cool"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I added a stage $limit and $skip for paging, if skip: 0, limit: 1 then the first record sometime is cool, sometime is hot. I also try to add stage $sort to make consistent order but it's not works.

My script with sort and limit, skip

```
db.getCollection('alerts').aggregate([{
  $match: {
    houseId: ObjectId("609100a56ed9f8001351aee3")
  }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: '$type',
        alerts: {
            $push: {
                _id: '$_id',
                type: '$type'
            }
        }
     }
  },
  {
    $project: {
       _id: false,
       type: '$_id.type',
       alerts: '$alerts'
    }

  },
  {
    $limit: limit + skip,
  },
  {
    $skip: skip,
  },
  {
    $sort: { type: 1 }
  }
])
```

My expected is the result return the same order

Comment: could you provide sort object ?

Comment: Insert stage `{$sort: {type: 1}}` before the `$group` stage.

Comment: @mohammadNaimi { sort: { type: 1 }}

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I push it at last stage. Because I think after limit, skip the result may reduce and sort operator will faster. But sort didn't work.

Comment: did you add skip and limit in aggregation ?

Comment: @mohammadNaimi Yes, I also added 1 script with skip, limit, sort on my question, please take a look

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I tried push it above $group stage but still not working

Comment: put sort top of limit in aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('alerts').aggregate([{
  $match: {
    houseId: ObjectId("609100a56ed9f8001351aee3")
  }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: '$type',
        alerts: {
            $push: {
                _id: '$_id',
                type: '$type'
            }
        }
     }
  },
  {
    $project: {
       _id: false,
       type: '$_id.type',
       alerts: '$alerts'
    }

  },
  {
    $sort: { type: 1 }
  },
  {
    $skip: skip,
  },
  {
    $limit: limit + skip,
  }
])
```

I changed the orders of `sort`,`limit` and `skip`

Comment: Why sort is not worked if I push it to below skip and limit ?

Comment: Add sort top of limit and skip

Comment: I want to know why sort is not worked if sort is below skip, limit

Comment: the reason I think returned to previous stage ($group) , the result at the stage is not sorted and when you apply to limit and skip it will return randomly and sort in last stage is not same at each query